# How to estimate the real amount of internet users who visits concrete site?

Tags: traffic-measurement, alexa-internet

Using Alexa.com I can find out that 0.05 % of all internet users visit some site, but how many people equals that 0.05% ?

Is there any facts like: in US 1% from Alexa statistics is nearly equals 15 mln of people, and in France 1% is about 3 mln of people, for example?

Answer (score 0):

Compete.com reckon that google has something like 147m monthly users, and alexa says they have 34% monthly. Ergo, you could estimate it to be approx 450million. That's one way of estimating...

Of course the data from both Compete and Alexa gets progressively more rubbish the smaller the site gets.  Data for the biggest sites is likely to be the least skewed, but I still wouldn't trust it for anything serious.

InternetWorldStats.com has a number of 1.6 billion internet users worldwide

Answer (score 0):

You can get world population statistics online - estimates are available here:

[Wikipedia World Population](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_population)

This will help you to rough-up some statistics, but you need to remember...

1. Population is not equal to "has an internet connection"
2. 0.5% does not really equate to "internet users" - it's more like 0.5% of people who are the kind of people that would install a random toolbar that offers them very little - so you need to bear in mind it's a certain "type" of person and that the statistics will be skewed (which is why www.alexa.com isn't ranked as EVERYONE with the Alexa toolbar is going to visit that website at some point
3. The smaller your website, the less accurate the statistics are. If you aren't in the top 100,000 websites in the world, the statistics become largely an anomaly as they "estimate up" the statistics from the toolbar users into an "average if everyone had a toolbar".

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Alexa doesn't show "X% of France users use this site". Instead it shows "X% of worldwide users use this site". So you don't have such information except the margin cases when 100% of site users are from one country.

Also most toolbars show just Alexa Rank. You can get online converter "Alexa Rank -> Monthly Traffic" here - http://netberry.co.uk/alexa-rank-explained.htm

Answer (score 0):

Well, here (http://netberry.co.uk/alexa-rank-explained.htm) is described a way to make a traffic estimation based on the alexa rank.  Basically, the author has offered an exponential function, not linear or polynomial.

There is also a **web service which aggregated alexa rank information and has already performed all the calculations**: http://www.rank2traffic.com/

I checked it, and for 80% of the websites the results are very satisfying. Still, there is 20% of (possibly, manipulated by webmasters) incorrect data (the estimated traffic is much higher than in reality)